# Searching file gives System.UnauthorizedAccessException trying to access protected system folders

Tags: vb.net, search, unauthorized

I don't like win7 file search, so I was trying to write a code to search for files and folders using a pattern like `*somechars*.doc*`

Here's my code:

```
'Look for files
If Me.CBox_Files.Checked Then
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(
            Me.TB_StartFolder.Text,
            FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories,
            Me.TB_Pattern.Text)
        LB_Files.Items.Add(foundFile)
    Next
End If
'Look for folders
If Me.CBox_Folders.Checked Then
    For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Me.TB_StartFolder.Text, Me.TB_Pattern.Text)
        LB_Folders.Items.Add(Dir)
    Next
End If
```

But it gives me `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` when I set root (`c:\`, `d:\` an so on) as starting folder.

I get error trying to access `c:\Documents and Settings` but i want to notice that I've tried to access this folder using explorer but it is forbidden (?)

I also tried to use a `try - catch` block but I wasn't able to get a collection of accessible folders: search result gives always nothing.

A good way could be to skip all forbidden folders but I woul like to get a list of all skipped folders.

**EDIT:**

I found useful informations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449700/filesystem-getfiles-unauthorizedaccessexception-error) but with the found code,  it seems that some folders are skipped even if accessible:
e.g.: If I set Desktop as start folder I can find a folder on the desktop, but if I set C:\ as start folder, the folder on the Desktop isn't found.

I also tried this code (and I get the same error)

```
Sub FileSearch(ByVal sDir As String)
    Dim d As String
    Dim f As String
    Try
        For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(sDir, Me.TB_Pattern.Text)
            LB_Files.Items.Add(f)
        Next
        For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
            For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(d, Me.TB_Pattern.Text)
                LB_Files.Items.Add(f)
                If LB_Files.Items.Count > CInt(Me.CboBox_Limit.SelectedItem) Then
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
            FileSearch(d)
        Next
    Catch excpt As System.Exception
        If Not d Is Nothing AndAlso d <> "" Then
            LB_SkippedFolders.Items.Add(d)
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

**EDIT 2:**

The exception is raised when the code tries to open a protected system-folder  (those directories that aren't usually shown in explorer).
So, my question is:
**How can I skip  all protected system-folders while searching?

Because when the error is raised the code stops searching!**

Comment: Your option is to program yourself the logic behind My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles and skip all folder that you don't have access to. [This could help](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/306666).

Comment: @the_lotus Thanks for the link, but even using `Directory.GetDirectories` and `Directory.GetFiles` some data are still missing: there are some folders that are inaccessible only if the search starts from root, but if I start searching from a subdirectory, then I can find match for the pattern.

Comment: That is strange, it would seem like you don't have access to a parent folder but do have access to it's child folder. There isn't much that can be done in that case.

Comment: @the_lotus I feared that it was so. I'll try some workaround...

Comment: @the_lotus I edited: the exception is raised by protected system folders

Comment: I think I encountered a similar problem once when trying to read directory symlinks.  It just didn't like the symlinks, so I ended up skipping them.  I doubt that helps you solve your current problem though.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I don't think I've understood what you've done but skipping the folders would be fine for me. Can you give me some hint?

Comment: I've added an answer showing how to skip a directory when you get an error reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to skip any directory that throws an error, you can do it this way:

```
For Each d In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
     Try
         For Each f In Directory.GetFiles(d, Me.TB_Pattern.Text)
             Try
                  LB_Files.Items.Add(f)
                  If LB_Files.Items.Count > CInt(Me.CboBox_Limit.SelectedItem) Then
                       Exit Sub
                  End If
             Catch ex as IOException
                   'This executes where there was an IO error
             End Try
          Next
          FileSearch(d)
     Catch ex as IOException
          'This executes where there was an IO error
     End Try
Next
```

I've added a Try / Catch block inside your loop that will allow the code to continue running if it encounters an `IOException`.  You could probably get more specific with the error type on the `Catch`, but I don't remember offhand exactly what type of error gets thrown in your situation.

Comment: Sorry but it still stops searching on errors, anyway I'm near: I skip folders but have duplicated results. If I found a solution I'll post it

Comment: you might need to wrap the inner loop with the same try catch block.  You didn't specify exactly which line was throwing the error, so I wasn't sure where to put the code.